# break from If without loops in java

Tags: java, break

I want to exit from a function if length of a string( originalPath.length) is equal to some specific number and this is restriction as well I cant do any other thing any idea?

```
String original = originalPath.substring(0, originalPath.length() - separatorPos);
```

this snippet is part of a function and not loop.

Comment: `if (condition) return;` (or `if (condition) return someValue;`)

Comment: actually the function return the processed strings so this wont work for me

Comment: @Eran Hm. We'd better get Brian Goetz in here to verify.

Comment: Do not execute for that length. If(!originalPath.length) { process }

Comment: basic programming construct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make a void method** and then 
You can do it using `if` condition and `return` **statement** like

```
if(condition){

return;
}
```

> `return` is used to stop further execution and return any value back from where it was called.

**There are other options  like throwing exceptions for the same and break,continue for loops in java**

Comment: I dnt need to return just to break from whole function altogether

Comment: then use void method,because any method declared void doesnt return any value

Answer (score 1):

You can use `return;` if your method is a `void`, otherwise just return a default value like `return false` to finish your method if the condition fails.

The `return` statement will finish your method.